# What exactly is streambuf? How do I use it?

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm trying to learn a bit more about how I/O streams work in C++, and I'm really confused at when to use what.

What exactly is a `streambuf`?
When do I use a `streambuf`, as compared to a `string`, an `istream`, or a `vector`? (I already know the last three, but not how `streambuf` compares to them, if it does at all.)

Comment: It's a bad abstraction of a stream buffer.

Comment: @Pubby: Er, what's a "stream buffer"? How is it different from a stream or a buffer?

Comment: From what I understand, a stream formats the in/output and stores it in it's buffer.

Comment: Read TC++PL SE (S) 21.6.

Comment: @moshbear: Sorry, I have no idea what that's referring to.

Comment: @Mehrdad Stroustrup's _The C++ Programming Language: Special Edition_

Comment: @moshbear: Oh... I'll buy that when I get the chance I guess, thanks.

Comment: It's to C++ as K&R is to C. That good.

Comment: If that is going to make you feel any better, I've worked with C++ for 15 years and still don't get the IO part of the C++ library. There wasn't a single project where I had a chance to use it.

Comment: I found this link's example code was pretty explanatory: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/rdbuf/

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Stream buffers represent input or output devices and provide a low level interface for unformatted I/O to that device. Streams, on the other hand, provide a higher level wrapper around the buffer by way of basic unformatted I/O functions and especially via formatted I/O functions (i.e., `operator<<` and `operator>>` overloads). Stream objects may also manage a stream buffer's lifetime.

For example a file stream has an internal file stream buffer. The stream manages the lifetime of the buffer and the buffer is what provides actual read and write capabilities to a file. The stream's formatting operators ultimately access the stream buffer's unformatted I/O functions, so you only ever have to use the stream's I/O functions, and don't need to touch the buffer's I/O functions directly.

Another way to understand the differences is to look at the different uses they make of locale objects. Streams use the facets that have to do with formatting such as `numpunct` and `num_get`. You can also expect that the overloads of stream `operator<<` and `operator>>` for custom time or money data types will use the time and money formatting facets. Stream buffers, however, use the codecvt facets in order to convert between the units their interface uses and bytes. So, for example, the interface for `basic_streambuf<char16_t>` uses `char16_t` and so `basic_streambuf<char16_t>` internally uses `codecvt<char16_t, char, mbstate_t>` by default to convert the formatted `char16_t` units written to the buffer to `char` units written to the underlying device. So you can see that streams are mostly for formatting and stream buffers provide a low level interface for unformatted input or output to devices which may use a different, external encoding.

You can use a stream buffer when you want only unformatted access to an I/O device. You can also use stream buffers if you want to set up multiple streams that share a stream buffer (though you'll have to carefully manage the lifetime of the buffer). There are also special purpose stream buffers you might want to use, such as `wbuffer_convert` in C++11 which acts as a façade for a `basic_streambuf<char>` to make it look like a wide character stream buffer. It uses the codecvt facet it's constructed with instead of using the codecvt facet attached to any locale. You can usually achieve the same effect by simply using a wide stream buffer imbued with a locale that has the appropriate facet.

Comment: This is 5 years too late, so I'm not going to post it as an answer and un-accept this one, but for anyone still confused by the terminology even after reading this: `streambuf` is for **raw** data (e.g. raw bytes, raw ints, etc.), whereas `stream` is for **cooked** data (text, integers formatted as text, etc.). Put another way, `stream` represents the **parsing** (or serialization) layer. When dealing with plain strings, you can technically use either, but the meaning is different: `streambuf` means you want the raw data to be the string itself, whereas `stream` abstracts away the encoding.

Comment: @Mehrdad May I ask what does it mean by saying *`stream` abstracts away the encoding*? :D Can you explain it a little bit more or provide some further material?

Comment: @Rick: Sure. `stream` is responsible for *reading and writing objects* to a `streambuf`. `streambuf` is responsible for *saving and restoring bytes* (or chars/words/whatever you prefer to call them) from a byte-storage location. The mapping between objects and bytes is what I was referring to as the "encoding". An example of this is that a `stream` would accept an `int` and then decide how to convert that into `char`s, and vice-versa -- it could use big-endian format, little-endian format, a bit-reversed format, a 7-bit-only format, or anything else. i.e. it abstracts away the storage format.

Answer (score 84):

With the help of `streambuf`, we can work in an even *lower level*. It allows access to the underlying buffers.

Here are some good examples : [Copy, load, redirect and tee using C++ streambufs](http://wordaligned.org/articles/cpp-streambufs) and in reference to comparison, This might be helpful,

[image]

See this for more details : [IOstream Library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/)

Comment: I searched all over for something that could explain streambuf's as well as this article. Thanks for helping me find it!

Comment: Example is always best. Thank you