# flock-ing a C++ ifstream on Linux (GCC 4.6)

Tags: c++, linux, g++, flock

#### context

I'm slowly writing a specialized web server application in C++ (using the C [onion http server library](https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion) and the [JSONCPP library](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/) for JSON serialization, if that matters)., for a Linux system with GCC 4.6 compiler (I don't care about portability to non Linux systems, or to GCC before 4.5 or to Clang before 3.0).

I decided to keep the user "database" (there will be very few users, probably one or two, so performance is not a concern, and O(n) access time is acceptable) in JSON format, probably as a small array of JSON objects like

```
 { "_user" : "basile" ;
   "_crypasswd" : "XYZABC123" ; 
   "_email" : "basile@starynkevitch.net" ;
   "firstname" : "Basile" ;
   "lastname" : "Starynkevitch" ;
   "privileges" : "all" ;
 }
```

with the convention (à la `.htpasswd`) that the `_crypasswd` field is the [crypt(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt) "encryption" of the user password, salted by the `_user` name;

The reason I want to describe users by Json objects is that my application might add (not replace) some JSON fields (like e.g. `privileges` above) in such Json objects describing users. I'm using *JsonCpp* as a Json parsing library for C++. This library wants an `ifstream` to be parsed.

So I am reading my password file with

```
extern char* iaca_passwd_path; // the path of the password file
std::ifstream jsinpass(iaca_passwd_path);
Json::Value jpassarr;
Json::Reader reader;
reader.parse(jsinpass,jpassarr,true);
jsinpass.close();
assert (jpassarr.isArray());
for (int ix=0; ix<nbu; ix++) {
  const Json::Value&jcuruser= jpassarr[ix];
  assert(jcuruser.isObject());
  if (jcuruser["_user"].compare(user) == 0) {
    std::string crypasswd = jcuruser["_crypasswd"].asString();
    if (crypasswd.compare(crypted_password(user,password)) == 0) {
         // good user
    }
  }
}
```

---

### question

Obviously, I want to [`flock`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock) or [`lockf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/lockf) the password file, to ensure that only one process is reading or writing it. To call these functions, I need to get the file descriptor (in Unix parlance) of the `ifstream jsinpass`. But Google gives me mostly [Kreckel's fileno](http://www.ginac.de/~kreckel/fileno/) (which I find complete, but a bit insane) to get the file descriptor of an `std::ifstream` and I am not sure that the constructor won't pre-read some of it. Hence my **question**:

#### how can I lock a C++ `ifstream` (Linux, GCC 4.6) ?

(Or do you find some other way to tackle that issue?)

Thanks

Comment: For getting the file descriptor, try http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_io.html  (disclaimer: I have not tried it myself)

Comment: Well, I am not sure to follow, how is that different from Kreckel's solution? Or are you suggesting I should construct an `std::ifstream` from an already `open(2)`-ed file descriptor? How?

Comment: Among your questions was how to get a file descriptor. I figured the function that GNU explicitly provides for that purpose would be useful.  If you wanted to construct a stream from an existing file descriptor, did you try looking at the `stdio_filebuf` class that the page mentions just for that purpose?

Comment: Sorry, I'm tired and it's making me a little grumpy. It's been a while since I've played with `streambuf`s, but IIRC once you make one, you pass it into the constructor for an `istream`. (or `ostream`, as appropriate) It's more convenient to make your own derived class of `istream` that handles the details for you. I don't have a reference handy, but it shouldn't be too hard to google, or maybe someone can post it as an answer if you're interested in that solution.

Comment: I am a bit confused about the relation between `stdio_filebuf` and `std::istream` (which is needed by JsonCpp)!

Comment: `flock()` is an advisory lock, what you want is `fcntl()`.

Comment: @fge: fcntl() is also advisory, unless you want to play with the Linux-specific mandatory flags (which require mount options, are buggy, and whatnot).

Comment: While the above is true since his file server is specialized I assume this means that he will deploy on a known platform, therefore he should configure it such that fcntl() works as he desires- however there is still no guarantee that many programs will cooperate.

Answer (score 4):

My solution to this problem is derived from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19749019/5899976

I've only tested it with GCC 4.8.5.

```
#include <cstring>  // for strerror()
#include <iostream> // for std::cerr
#include <fstream>
#include <ext/stdio_filebuf.h>

extern "C" {
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/file.h>  // for flock()
}

    // Atomically increments a persistent counter, stored in /tmp/counter.txt
int increment_counter()
{
    std::fstream file( "/tmp/counter.txt" );
    if (!file) file.open( "/tmp/counter.txt", std::fstream::out );

    int fd = static_cast< __gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf< char > * const >( file.rdbuf() )->fd();
    if (flock( fd, LOCK_EX ))
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to lock file: " << strerror( errno ) << "\n";
    }

    int value = 0;
    file >> value;
    file.clear();   // clear eof bit.
    file.seekp( 0 );
    file << ++value;

    return value;

    // When 'file' goes out of scope, it's closed.  Moreover, since flock() is
    //  tied to the file descriptor, it gets released when the file is closed.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a separate lockfile rather than trying to get the descriptor from the `ifstream`. It's much easier to implement, and you could probably wrap the `ifstream` in a class that automates this.

If you want to ensure atomic open/lock, You might want to construct a stream using the method suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2746300), following `open` and `flock`

Comment: Note: You probably don't want to use Sutur's RWLock as is, it appears to contain a memory leak and doesn't use `flock`/`lockf` etc

Comment: Suter's RWLock is also racy; I filed a bug and the suggestion has been removed from the libstdc++ docs (give it a day or so to propagate to the webpage).

Comment: @janneb: It was also fairly difficult to find. I'm removing it from my answer in any case, since it doesn't really illustrate much other than using a lockfile.

Answer (score 1):

A deficiency with the filestream API is that you cannot (at least not [easily](https://www.ginac.de/~kreckel/fileno/)) access the file descriptor of an fstream (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558447/retrieving-file-descriptor-from-a-stdfstream) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109449/getting-a-file-from-a-stdfstream), for example). This is because there is no requirement that fstream is implemented in terms of FILE* or file descriptors (though in practice it always is).
This is also required for using pipes as C++ streams.

Therefore the 'canonical' answer (as implied in the comments to the question) is:

create a [stream buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116541/what-exactly-is-streambuf-how-do-i-use-it) (derived from std::basic_streambuf) that uses Posix and C stdio I/O functions (i.e open etc) and thus gives access to the file descriptor.

Create your own 'LockableFileStream' (derived from std::basic_iostream) using your stdio based stream buffer instead of std::streambuf.

You may now have a fstream like class from which you may gain access to the file descriptor and thus use fcntl (or lockf) as appropriate.

There are a few libraries which provide this out of the box.

I had thought this was addressed partly now that we've reached C++17 but I can't find the link so I must have dreamed it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the traditional unix-y solution of relying on the atomicity of rename() unacceptable?

I mean, unless your JSON serialization format supports in-place update (with a transaction log or whatever), then updating your password database entails rewriting the entire file, doesn't it? So you might as well write it to a temporary file, then rename it over the real name, thus ensuring that readers read a consistent entry? (Of course, in order for this to work each reader must open() the file each time it wants to access a DB entry, leaving the file open doesn't cut it)

Comment: If two processes try to do this at the same time, then the second process could overwrite changes made by the first process. It's not enough for `rename()` to be atomic to avoid this scenario (well, at least it avoids file corruption).

Comment: A process that wishes to edit the file should rename it, edit it, then rename ut back. This is race-free.