# Retrieving file descriptor from a std::fstream

Tags: c++, fstream, file-descriptor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting a FILE* from a std::fstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109449/getting-a-file-from-a-stdfstream)

I am working on Linux and file descriptors are the main model in this OS.

I was wondering whether is there any library or any way to retrieve the native Linux file descriptor starting from a C++ `std::fstream`.

I thought about `boost::iostream` since there is a class called `file_descriptor` but I understood that its purpose is different from the one I want to achieve.

Do you know some way to do that?

Comment: Why do you need the file descriptor?

Comment: I am looking also to NON-Standard since I will stick to Linux platform. I found this page as well. Anyone used it?Anyhttp://www.ginac.de/~kreckel/fileno/

Comment: This question is not a duplicate.  This question asks how to get a file descriptor from an iostream.  A file descriptor is a low-level kernel concept.  The question pointed to as the original of which this is supposedly a duplicate speaks of FILE * streams, which are not the same.

Comment: Related (since the cited duplicate is *not* a duplicate *per se*): [What's the difference between a file descriptor and file pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2423628/608639)

Comment: Personally, after performing a write, I need to determine the size of the file - frequently! `file.seekg( 0, std::ios::end ); fsize = file.tellg(); file.seekg( 0, std::ios::end ); fsize = file.tellg() - fsize;` on some filesystems can take a loooong time. Meanwhile, `fstat()` on an open file descriptor is lightning-fast.

Comment: I agree with OP that it's not a duplicate - file descriptors and FILE * are different.  My solution is shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53689083/5899976  As with the selected answer, it depends on a non-portable GCC extension.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can go the other way: implement your own stream buffer that wraps a file descriptor and then use it with `iostream` instead of `fstream`. Using [Boost.Iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) can make the task easier.

Non-portable gcc solution is:

```
#include <ext/stdio_filebuf.h>

{
    int fd = ...;
    __gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf<char> fd_file_buf{fd, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary};
    std::ostream fd_stream{&fd_file_buf};
    // Write into fd_stream.
    // ...
    // Flushes the stream and closes fd at scope exit.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no (standard) way to extract the file number from an std::fstream since the standard library does not mandate how file streams will be implemented.

Rather, you need to use the C file API if you want to do this (using `FILE*`).

Comment: This seems to give the advantage to C over C++ for Unix system programming.

Answer (score 4):

There is no official way to get the private file handle of a file stream (or actualy a [`std::basic_filebuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf)), just because it should be portable and discourage use of platform-specific functions.

However, you can do ugly hack like inheriting `std::basic_filebuf` and from that try to pry out the file handle. It's not something I recommend though as it will probably break on different versions of the C++ library.

Answer (score 2):

There is no support of exposing file descriptor neither in standard C++ nor in `libstdc++`.