# Decrypt of file displays both original and cipher text?

Tags: c++, aes, crypto++, cbc-mode

I am working to encrypt and decrypt files using Crypto++. In encryption, `key`  and random `IV` are generated and `hexencoded` where as text from file is encrypted. Both `IV` and `cipher` text are written to the same file.

In decryption, `key` is generated using same criteria as encryption and random `IV` is extracted from the file and `hexdecoded`. Text after `iv` length is stored in a string and decrypted.

What happens is I can see the original file so I know that it is working but it also displays `cipher` text after the original file text. Does any one how to solve it?

```
 //some code to declare variables, read from file and so on 

  unsigned char * inputContent = (unsigned char *) malloc(fileSize * sizeof(char));     //create char array of same size as file content 

 //inputContent is for storing file data    

  string rawString(reinterpret_cast<char*>(inputContent), fileSize);        //convert char array to string

  //extract iv, key and cipher from rawString
  string rawIV;
  rawIV = rawString.substr(0, 32);

  //code to hexdecode iv

  string cipher;
  cipher = rawString.substr(32, fileSize - 32);

  string recovered;

  CBC_Mode< AES >::Decryption d;
  d.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv);

  StringSource s_recover(cipher, true, 
      new StreamTransformationFilter(d,
                new StringSink(recovered)
            )
        );  

  const char * writeContent = recovered.c_str();

  if(pwrite(fd, writeContent, recovered.length(), 0) <= 0)
  {
      return -1;    //error
  }
```

Thanks in advance. ☺

Comment: any specific reason you're using `pwrite`?

Comment: @deW1 No. I tried using `write` but same result

Comment: Yeah just the file. But I need to add iv to the key after encryption and then extract it from file before decryption so I wasn't sure if `FileSource` would help

Comment: @jww Also I dont know how to use `FileSource` with integer file descriptor

Comment: @jww this project is more like a **change request**. File is already been read through different functions and in that function I am calling `encrypt(fd)` and `decrypt(fd)`

Comment: @jww I dont like mixing C and C++ either but I dont have any choice except for `read/pread` and `write/pwrite` but for **Crypto++** I have to convert them to string

Comment: @jww TBH, even I dont know the on-disk layout of the structure. I am new to programming in linux. But I am looking at the links you posted and see if that might help. Although, I can read the `iv` from the file and decrypt the file content, the problem is with writing to the file. Thanks for the link tho. If it helps, I am executing on a VM VirtualBox with default settings

Comment: @jww I am sorry if you think I am wasting your time. I am genuinely answering to the best of my knowledge. When encrypting, IV + cipher text is stored in the file. After `hexencoding` its 32 characters. So in `decrypt` function, I am reading first 32 characters and `hexdecoding` to regenerate same iv and the rest of the file content are cipher text. As for the `key`, it will be the same every time

Comment: @jww I wished you hadn't deleted the answer as it really contained some useful information for new learner. Maybe next time I ask a question, I could properly answer them.

Comment: @user4812502 - the answer was accumulating down votes. I suspect because its not clear what you are trying to do or what your problem is. There's no sense in leaving it up. Plus, you can find all the information on the [Crypto++ wiki](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Main_Page).

Comment: @jww So far it has accumulated exactly 1 nett downvote. You were a bit trigger-happy IMO. You should have more confidence. If you think it's correct, leave it there. Some people will downvote anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try something like this. But its hard to say if it will actually work since its not clear what you are actually doing or where the problem lies.

```
FileSource fs("<filename>", false /*pumpAll*/);    
SecByteBlock key(AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH), iv(AES::BLOCKSIZE);

// Fetch key from somewhere
key = ...;

// Fetch IV from file
fs.Detach(new HexDecoder(new ArraySink(iv, iv.size()));
fs.Pump(32);

CBC_Mode< AES >::Decryption dec;
dec.SetKeyWithIV(key, key.size(), iv, iv.size());

string recovered;
fs.Detach(new HexDecoder(new StreamTransformationFilter(dec, new StringSink(recovered))));
fs.PumpAll();
```

You can also use the following *if* you get the [`SecByteBlockSink` patch](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/SecByteBlockSink):

```
SecByteBlock recovered;
fs.Detach(new HexDecoder(new StreamTransformationFilter(dec, new SecByteBlockSink(recovered))));
fs.PumpAll();
```

---

`rawString` isn't needed below:

```
//create char array of same size as file content 
unsigned char * inputContent = (unsigned char *) malloc(fileSize * sizeof(char));     

//inputContent is for storing file data    

//convert char array to string
string rawString(reinterpret_cast<char*>(inputContent), fileSize);
```

Maybe you should try:

```
ArraySource as(inputContent, fileSize, false /*pumpAll*/);
```

Using the [`ArraySource`](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/ArraySource) means you don't make a copy of the data (the `string` copies the data), and its ready to go for Crypto++.

Also, since you're already into C++ code, use an `unique_ptr` and `new` rather than `malloc`. The `unique_ptr` will handle cleanup for you. (Or, use a `std::vector`).

```
unique_ptr<byte[]> buffer(new byte[fileSize]);
```

---

I don't know how you are going to make a file descriptor work in the grand scheme of things. Crypto++ is a C++ library, and C++ uses I/O streams. Maybe this will help: [How to construct a c++ fstream from a POSIX file descriptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2746168)

Also see [Retrieving file descriptor from a std::fstream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11558447) and [Getting a FILE* from a std::fstream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/109449).