# How to open an ifstream from a file descriptor?

Tags: c++, file, s3fs

I am trying to implement an encryption on a file through s3fs using rc4. Basically I need to take a file descriptor that s3fs gives use it to extract the name of the file and then do the thing. So how would I do that in c++?

I don't have any code to show because I don't know how to start it  would look something like:

```
void foo(int fd){
// something

string temp; 
temp = // result of that somethingthing;
ifstream in;
in.open(temp,ios::binary | ios::in);
}
```

Is this even doable? Or am I just doomed to use system calls?

Comment: Use C functions to read into a character buffer, then convert that character buffer into a `std::string` and then a `std::stringstream`, perhaps?

Comment: @EhabEl-Nabarawy the approaches listed there don't work on my system. I'm trying to `jerry-rig` a solution using tadman's suggestion which seems to kind of work. Not 100% sure yet.

Comment: @Caleb Oh, oops, FUSE-based, my apologies!

Comment: No problem thanks for the help though. I think I've managed to accomplish my goal exclusively with system calls but I still have some errors. I may post again in a few days if I cannot debug

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer:** you can't, not in standard C++ anyway. There is no official/portable way to do it.

You **can**, however, find some "work-around" solutions in these previous posts:

[How to construct a c++ fstream from a POSIX file descriptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746168/how-to-construct-a-c-fstream-from-a-posix-file-descriptor)

[Getting a FILE* from a std::fstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109449/getting-a-file-from-a-stdfstream)

[Retrieving file descriptor from a std::fstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558447/retrieving-file-descriptor-from-a-stdfstream)