# Can I do something to a `int file = open(path, flag);`?

Tags: c++

Are there any methods/functions that can I use with `int file = open(filepath, flag);` because I am trying to implement `flock` and because `ifstream file; file.open("filepath");` won't work with `flock()` ?

I am trying to learn how to implement `flock()` in C++ and I have found some examples online. This is what I've written:

```
  int file;
  char configPath[] = "data/configuration.txt";
  file = open(configPath, O_RDONLY);
  if(file != -1) {
    std::cout<<"Successfully opened file: "<<configPath<<std::endl;
    if(flock(file,1) == 0) {
      //do things with the file
    }
  }
```

But now I don't know how to do things with the file.
I would like to get the content line by line.

Here is how I did it before:

```
int readConfig(std::ifstream& configFile, std::string (&string)[10], int counter) {
  std::cout<<"void readConfiguration\n";
  if(!configFile) {
    std::cout<<"configuration.txt couldn't be opened\n";
  } else {
      // Get content line by line of txt file
      int i = 0;
      while(getline(configFile,string[i++]));
      //for debug only
      for(int k = 0; k<i; k++) std::cout<<"string[k]= "<<string[k]<<"\n";
    }

    return counter;
}

  configFile.open("data/configuration.txt");
  std::string inputs[10];
  int counter;
  readConfig(configFile, inputs, counter);
```

But I can't use `flock()` when I open the file using `std::ifstream::open()` because `flock()` takes two `ints` as arguments:

```
extern int flock (int __fd, int __operation) __THROW;
```

## EDIT:

This is what I came up with help from @MSalters :

```
int readConfig(std::istream& configFile, std::string (&string)[10], int counter) {
  std::cout<<"void readConfiguration\n";
  if(!configFile) {
    std::cout<<"configuration.txt couldn't be opened\n";
  } else {
      // Get content line by line of txt file
      int i = 0;
      while(getline(configFile, string[i++]));
      //for debug only
      for(int k = 0; k<i; k++) std::cout<<"string[k]= "<<string[k]<<"\n";
      counter = i;
    }
    return counter;
}

int main()
{
  int file;
  char configPath[] = "data/configuration.txt";
  file = open(configPath, O_RDONLY);
  if(file != -1) {
    std::cout<<"Successfully opened file: "<<configPath<<std::endl;
    if(flock(file,1) == 0) {
      __gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf<char> fd_file_buf{file, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary};
      std::istream fd_stream{&fd_file_buf};
      std::string inputs[10];
      int counter;
      readConfig(fd_stream, inputs, counter);
      flock(file,8);
      file = close(file);
    }
  }
}
```

It compiles and runs, but `std::cout<<"string[k]= "<<string[k]<<"\n";` returns `string[k]=`  and that's it.

## EDIT2:

I have a web-page written in PHP that gives the user the ability to input 6 values:

```
URL
URL Refresh Interval
Brightness
Color1 in hex
Color2 in hex
Color3 in hex
```

These values will be written in `configuration.txt`.

Each time the web-page is accessed `configuration.txt` gets opened, the PHP gets some values from there and then closes it.
`configuration.txt` is also opened when one or more of the above values are submitted and then it gets closed.

Next, I have a bash that regularly `wgets` the URL from `configuration.txt` and writes the output to a different file, called `url_response.txt`.

```
while [ 0 ]
do
    line=$(head -n 1 data/configuration.txt)
    wget -q -i $line -O url_response.txt
    sleep 2
done
```

This script will be put inside a C++ program.

Finally, the same C++ program will have to access `url_response.txt` to get and parse some strings from it and it will also have to access `configuration.txt` to get the three colors from it.

So I want to implement `flock()` in all of these programs.

Everything will run on a Raspberry Pi 4 that runs on Linux raspberrypi 4.19.58-v7l+.

Comment: Use the "regular" C file interface?

Comment: @molbdnilo If I knew how to do that or even what that was I wouldn't have posted here, would I ? I am reading online on what I need and what I can use ! But I do not have the big picture, nor the knowledge. I am learning on the go.

Comment: Here is what you can do with the `int file`: [C-style file input/output](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c)

Comment: @acraig5075: Nope, that's with a C style `FILE*`. This is with a POSIX `int fd`.

Comment: Meaning that I need to read here: https://www.mkompf.com/cplus/posixlist.html#files_and_directories
?

Comment: @bleah1: Much simpler - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11558715/15416. Gcc has a C++ class to wrap the `int fd` from `open()` (and clang too, I think).

Comment: @MSalters That basically means that it transforms `int fd = open()` into an `ifstream file`, correct ? I am not sure about the gcc part, because I will run this project on the Raspberry and I have no idea which compiler it uses. This gets harder and harded...

Comment: @bleah1: Technically, into an `istream file` (the base class of `ifstream`) but that doesn't matter for `>>` and `<<`. Raspberry's generally use GCC. The chief not-GCC platform is Windows where you mostly see Microsoft Visual C++

Comment: Sooo... `__gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf<char> fd_file_buf{file, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary};
  std::ostream fd_stream{&fd_file_buf};` is way over my understanding. Which one is the newly created stream file ? Is it `fd_file_buf` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199008/discussion-between-bleah1-and-msalters).

Comment: @bleah1 commendation for a full description. I am not bash aficionado, but I am wondering how did C++ came into question? Would this not be possible to develop in bash only? Including the file locking too?

Comment: @ChefGladiator I actually thought of something else. And it doesn't involve `flock` at all. I will put the script inside the c++ program. And the files will be accessed in an orderly fashion. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57822336/system-path-to-bash-returns-file-txt-permission-denied

Comment: Technically you are not putting the script inside the program. You are calling it from the program.  That confused me a lot. Still, I can not see why exactly you use compiled C++ programs. Why is not the entire solution made of one or more bash scripts?

Comment: @ChefGladiator Because the rest of the program consists of using this: https://github.com/hzeller/rpi-rgb-led-matrix

Comment: @bleah1 I suggest you need to rethink the architecture of your app. I might be so bold to  suggest to do this with C++/C written service(s) running on Raspbery.  Used from javascript running from behind a browser. In that scenario all of your app server side, is written in C++ and running on the Raspbery side. I was told this is worth looking at -- http://cppmicroservices.org/ -- date is still 2017 though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it can be easily done with C API.
Use family of functions for file IO inherited from C: `fopen()`, `fclose()`, `fgets()` and so on.

Simple file read example to start with (and [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen) to docs). Just add your looking routines where needed.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    FILE* fp = std::fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if(!fp) {
        std::perror("File opening failed");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int c; // note: int, not char, required to handle EOF
    while ((c = std::fgetc(fp)) != EOF) { // standard C I/O file reading loop
       std::putchar(c);
    }

    if (std::ferror(fp))
        std::puts("I/O error when reading");
    else if (std::feof(fp))
        std::puts("End of file reached successfully");

    std::fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: And just to mention, C API is typically what you need when implementing your own low-level routines to replace on from C++ STL.

Comment: And where can I add `flock()` there ? I don't really want to use C, because things will get hard fast.

Comment: It's still a long way to go. File locks may be implemented via file-lock table (stored in a lock-file in the current directory). If so you shall put flock() before opening a file (and flock() in its turn will encapsulate opening of and reading from a file-lock table).
Anyway check whether lock is free (and locking if so) will go before working file IO.

Comment: @bleah1 by your own admission you do not know a lot, which is fine, but you seem to know "things will get hard fast" if you try the C routines as patient people have suggested. That  seems like a veteran developer opinion. Sadly wrong.

Comment: @ChefGladiator nice thoughts. But using C routines without being aware of what you doing is generally a bad idea, even though there is quite a big project with plain C++ of the latest standard %)

Comment: @ChefGladiator Mate, I would love to know what I'm talking about, but I don't. I have been coding for the past half a year on a daily basis and before that I studied C and C++ in high school and at the uni.  I wouldn't call me a veteran. I know that C is hard because I saw a lot of threads with C in them when I was looking for my answers. And also, if you search: "Is C hard" or "How hard is C" everybody will tell you the same thing: that C is very hard to learn, understand and use.

Comment: @bleah1 C might be hard, but IMHO it's a lot simpler and cleaner than C++, which has the tendency to include every feature under the sun and make the syntax so complex and difficult to read

Comment: @bleah1 it's OK that you prefer not to use what you don't know well. Proficient codding in C is worth years of developing and supporting big applications and libraries. But knowing general features of C language is very useful for C++ programmer it's OK to use such knowledge (of C programming) when needed with high attention to details, coding rules, best practices and common mistakes even in C++ coding (especially while writing libraries).

Comment: @bleah1 please do let us know a lot more about your requirement: what is the OS you want/need to run on? C++17? As an examle WIN32 LockFile might be just what you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-lockfile ...  but then I am not even sure do you wnt to know how is `flock` implemented ot you simply want to read file contents using what seems to be C API? Plese edit and clarify your question.

Comment: Done ! I've edited it and added all of the details.

Comment: @f4f cutting a potato without "knowing of what you doing" is a bad idea too ..same applies to every software building activity. I have to say I am trying, last few years, to convince myself not to go back to C, after two decades of C++ in the meantime.