# system("/path/to/bash.sh") returns file.txt: Permission denied only when c++ program is ran as root

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi

The project is on a Raspberry Pi 4 that runs Linux raspberrypi 4.19.58-v7l+ .

I have the following `get_page.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

line=$(head -n 1 ../configuration.txt)
wget -q -i $line -O url_response.txt
```

I have a c++ program named `Big_ppd_display_try1` that calls the above mentioned script:

```
int readConfig(std::ifstream& configFile, std::string (&string)[10]) {
  std::cout<<"Inside int readConfig\n";
  int counter=0;
  if(!configFile) {
    std::cout<<"configuration.txt couldn't be opened\n";
  } else {
      // Get content line by line of txt file
      int i = 0;
      while(getline(configFile, string[i++]));
      //for debug only      
      for(int k = 0; k<i; k++) std::cout<<"string["<<k<<"]= "<<string[k]<<"\n";
      counter = i-1;
    }
    return counter;
}

int main() {
  while(true) {
    std::cout<<"-------------------------------------------"<<std::endl;
    system("/var/www/html/4panel/get_page.sh");

    char urlResponsePath[]="url_response.txt";
    std::ifstream urlResponseFile;
    urlResponseFile.open(urlResponsePath, std::ifstream::in);
    if(urlResponseFile.is_open()) {
      std::cout<<"Successfully opened file: "<<urlResponsePath<<std::endl;
      std::string inputs[10];
      int lines;
      lines = readConfig(urlResponseFile, inputs);
      std::cout<<"# of lines: "<<lines<<std::endl;
    } else {
      std::cout<<"Error, Could not open file: "<<urlResponsePath<<std::endl;
    }
    usleep(2000*1050);
  }

 return 0;
}
```

This c++ program is executed like this: `sudo ./Big_ppd_display_try1`

The code written above should:

- call the script;
- the script should re-write `url_response.txt` with the body of the URL taken from `configuration.txt` : `line=$(head -n 1 ../configuration.txt)`;
- open `url_response.txt`
- copy the contents of `url_response.txt` line by line in `std::string inputs[10];`

The problem is that I get the following error:

```
url_response.txt: Permission denied
```

All the files are in `/var/www/html/4panel`
These are the permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data pi  4096 Aug 24 01:57 4panel

-rwxrwxrwx  1 pi pi 1080684 Aug 24 01:57 Big_ppd_display_try1
-rw-rw-r--  1 pi pi    5739 Aug 24 01:57 Big_ppd_display_try1.cc
-rw-r--r--  1 pi pi  255660 Aug 24 01:57 Big_ppd_display_try1.o
-rw-r--r--  1 pi pi    1082 Aug 23 21:33 Makefile
-rwxrwxrwx  1 pi pi      90 Aug 24 01:46 get_page.sh
-rw-rw-rw-  1 pi pi      56 Aug 23 20:26 url.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 pi pi       0 Aug 24 01:52 url_response.txt
```

I am not a prolific Linux user and as such I have very little knowledge of file permissions, commands and things like -n -i -l -a etc.

## EDIT:

Executing the c++ program without sudo: `./Big_ppd_display_try1` doesn't return the `url_response.txt: Permission denied` error.
But I need to run the program with `sudo` because the rest of the code consists of using [hzeller's rgb led matrix library](https://github.com/hzeller/rpi-rgb-led-matrix) and that requires the program to run as root: *"not running as root which means we can't properly control timing unless this is a real-time kernel. This will seriously mess with color stability and flicker    of the matrix."*

## EDIT2:

The program drops the privileges from `root` to `daemon` after the hardware is initialized to minimize the security issues. But when forced to keep running as `root` the `Permission denied` error would not show up, effectively fixing my issue.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199098/discussion-on-question-by-bleah1-system-path-to-bash-sh-returns-file-txt-pe).