# Read an entire line including spaces from fstream

Tags: c++, fstream

I am currently working on a small project in C++ and am a bit confused at the moment. I need to read a certain amount of words in a line that is taken from a file using ifstream in(). The problem with it right now is the fact that it keeps ignoring spaces. I need to count the amount of spaces within the file to calculate the number of words. Is there anyway to have in() not ignore the white space?

```
ifstream in("input.txt");       
ofstream out("output.txt");

while(in.is_open() && in.good() && out.is_open())
{   
    in >> temp;
    cout << tokencount(temp) << endl;
}
```

Comment: [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: Could you include a code snippet in your question? Answers can be much more specific when the question is clearer.

Comment: You can configure whether C++ streams should ignore whitespace or not, it's called "skipws", if I remember correctly.

Comment: That while condition is so silly I don't even how to comment on it. Do  you even `fstream::operator bool()`?

Comment: What @Griwes means is you can just do while(in) {...}

Comment: @NathanMonteleone, seriously, do you have to make things *that* easy?

Answer (score 3):

To count the number of spaces in a file:

```
std::ifstream inFile("input.txt");
std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it (inFile), end;
int numSpaces = std::count(it, end, ' ');
```

To count the number of whitespace characters in a file:

```
std::ifstream inFile("input.txt");
std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it (inFile), end;
int numWS = std::count_if(it, end, (int(*)(int))std::isspace);
```

As an alternative, instead of counting *spaces*, you could count *words*.

```
std::ifstream inFile("foo.txt);
std::istream_iterator<std::string> it(inFile), end;
int numWords = std::distance(it, end);
```

Comment: +1 for the istreambuf_iterator<char> trick.  I was wondering if there was something along those lines that would let you do it with a single iterator for the whole file :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
std::ifstream fs("input.txt");
std::string line;
while (std::getline(fs, line)) {
    int numSpaces = std::count(line.begin(), line.end(), ' ');
}
```

In general, if I have to do something for every line of a file, I find std::getline to be the least finicky way of doing it.  If I need stream operators from there I'll end up making a stringstream out of just that line.  It's far from the most efficient way of doing things but I'm usually more concerned with getting it right and moving on with life for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `count` with an `istreambuf_iterator`:

```
ifstream fs("input.txt");

int num_spaces = count(istreambuf_iterator<unsigned char>(fs),
                       istreambuf_iterator<unsigned char>(),
                       ' ');
```

**edit**

Originally my answer used `istream_iterator`, however as `@Robᵩ` pointed out it doesn't work.

`istream_iterator` will iterate over a stream, but assume whitespace formatting and skip over it. My example above but using `istream_iterator` returned the result zero, as the iterator skipped whitespace and then I asked it to count the spaces that were left.

`istreambuf_iterator` however takes one raw character at a time, no skipping.

See [`istreambuf_iterator` vs `istream_iterator`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564013/c-streams-confusion-istreambuf-iterator-vs-istream-iterator) for more info.

Comment: That [code](http://ideone.com/hc2vrS) doesn't do what you think it does. In fact, it always returns zero.