# C++ istreambuf_iterator template parameter

Tags: c++, streambuf, istream-iterator

Based on this question: [C++ streams confusion: istreambuf_iterator vs istream_iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564013/c-streams-confusion-istreambuf-iterator-vs-istream-iterator) on `istreambuf_iterator`, my understanding is that `istreambuf_iterator` is an iterator for raw input rather than formatted input. In that case, is it correct to assume that the template parameter of `istreambuf_iterator` can only be those related to `char`, such as `istreambuf_iterator<char>`, `istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t>`, and that something like `istreambuf_iterator<int>` would be invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can only use the streambuf iterators to read "characters", since it gets characters directly from the buffer. There's no formatted input involved which means it can not convert the data.