# overriding `istream operator>>` vs using `sscanf`

Tags: c++, scanf, istream

Say I wanted to initialise a `std::vector` of objects e.g.

`class Person { int ID; string name; ...}`

from a file that contains a line for each object. One route, is to override `operator>>` and simply `std::cin>>temp_person`, another - which I used to favour is to use `sscanf("%...", &...)` a bunch of temporary primitive types and simply `.emplace_back(Person(temp_primitives...)`.

Which way achieves the quickest runtime ignoring memory footprint? Is there any point in `mmap()`ing the entire file?

Comment: *Which way achieves the quickest runtime ignoring memory footprint?* `sscanf/fscanf` is probably tad faster but it might not be sigfnificant. Give it a shot and find out the difference.

Comment: "*Which way achieves the quickest runtime ignoring memory footprint?*" - profile the code and find out for yourself

Comment: Since you asked about `mmap` performance, see my answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172740/how-does-mmap-improve-file-reading-speed/37173063#37173063 and more to the point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33616284/read-line-by-line-in-the-most-efficient-way-platform-specific/33620968#33620968

Comment: Overloading `operator>>` mostly determines the syntax for calling it. If you want to implement that using `scanf`, that's pretty trivial to do. In other words, this isn't really an either/or situation. You can do one or both as you see fit.

Comment: The `sscanf` does not have format specifiers for `std::string`.

Comment: You can use `std::cin` and `>>` without overloading the `>>` operator. Just read into a temporary object and push it into the vector like you do with `sscanf`. Might as well stick with C++ I/O if you don't need to use C I/O.

Comment: Note: If you are using std::cin rather than a file. Remember to unlink the C++ buffer from the C buffer. That will improve performance. [`std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio)

Comment: @MartinYork, unfortunately I do need to mix C/C++ io, otherwise it’s sound advice.

Comment: @AlexPetrosyan I question the "Need". You may happen to have C code mixed with your C++. But need is a strong word. You just don't want to pay the effort to re-factor it out. Which could be a valid choice. But mixing these completely different languages you will not get the full power of C++. Pick one language it makes things simpler in the long run.

Comment: @MartinYork, I understand what you mean, but sometimes you simply can't refactor the code out, e.g. when you're using an external library and you're not allowed to touch it (my case).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are reading from a file, the performance is going to be I/O-bound. Almost no matter what you do in memory, the effect on the overall performance is not going to be detectable.

I would prefer the `operator>>` route, because this would let me use the input iterator idiom of C++:

```
std::istream_iterator<Person> eos;
std::istream_iterator<Person> iit(inputFile);
std::copy(iit, eos, std::back_inserter(person_vector));
```

or even

```
std::vector<Person>   person_vector(
    std::istream_iterator<Person>(inputFile)
,   std::istream_iterator<Person>()
);
```

Comment: Beat me to it. :-). But you can also use the `std::vector<Person>` constructor that takes two iterators: `std::vector<Person>   person_vector(iit, eos);`

Comment: @MartinYork Thank you very much, that makes perfect sense!

Comment: @AlexPetrosyan Sure, `std::istreambuf_iterator<Person>` should work as well. I am not sure what advantages you would get from operating on the "raw" character level, though.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I think this is the exact use case for buffered io. In Java, `bufferedReader` when used to read objects from standard input(s), will not construct temporary objects for assignment on a character by character, but rather object by object basis. In my case this leads to a performance bump, so I think it’s worthwhile.

Comment: @AlexPetrosyan In C++ the implementation is very different, so "raw characters" means something else. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34458016/335858) for a very detailed explanation of what's different (spoiler: not much).