# the difference betwen `istreambuf_iterator` and `istream_iterator`

Tags: c++

1. What is the difference betwen `istreambuf_iterator` and `istream_iterator`.
2. For the following code:

   ```
    istream_iterator<int> cin_in(cin);
    istream_iterator<int> end;
   ```

   where does the iterator `end` point to?
   Will the iterator bind with the stream?
   If I write the code

   ```
   istream_iterator<int>()
   ```

   is it the same as `end`?
3. And where is that all documented?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents)

Comment: @Deduplicator   hi, thanks for replying.. I have read the link you include in the comment and I find there are so many answers there and I do not know which one is helpful... I am a new in C++ and it is a little bit difficult for me to read too complicated stuff..

Comment: Also see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator `end` is known as a sentinel, it does not point anywhere specific.

Comment: @Deduplicator  and is it binded with the stream? since I find the code :  `std::vector<char> v( (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in)),
                          std::istreambuf_iterator<char>() );` I do not quite understand the second parameter, `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()` , where is it pointing to?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564013/c-streams-confusion-istreambuf-iterator-vs-istream-iterator

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116541/what-exactly-is-streambuf-how-do-i-use-it

Answer (score 16):

> What is the difference betwen `istreambuf_iterator` and `istream_iterator`.

`std::istream_iterator` is an iterator for formatted extraction. For instance, if you have a line of integers from a file and wish to copy them to some container, you would use `std::istream_iterator<int>` which internally will copy the value extracted from an `int` (using `operator>>()`) to the container:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(file),
          std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(some_container));
```

`std::istreambuf_iterator` is an iterator for unformatted extraction. It works directly on the `std::streambuf` object provided through its constructor. As such, if you need simply the contents of the file without worrying about their format, use this iterator. For example, sometimes you want to read an entire file into a string or some container. A regular formatted extractor will discard leading whitespace and convert extracted tokens; the buffer iterator will not:

```
std::string str(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{file}, {});
```

> Where does the iterator end point to?

A default-constructed stream iterator is simply a special sentinel object that represents the end of the stream. Since IOStreams are one-pass, there's no way for it to actually point to the end until we have read up to that point. Internally, when an extraction has failed or the read hit the end-of-file, the iterator that was constructed with a stream (or stream buffer) will change into an end stream iterator. This is what helps standard algorithms work with stream iterators, since they act like regular iterators on the outside.

> And where is that all documented?

Many places. Formally in the Standard. You can also find documentation on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com).

Comment: Nice answer ! Thanks