# Which stream is suitable for serialization over UDP?

Tags: c++, network-programming, boost-asio, boost-serialization

I am trying to serialize and recover objects over UDP using the *[Boost.Serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)* and *[Boost.Asio](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)* libraries. The following points sum up what I know so far:

- The main concept of *Boost.Serialization* is the **archive**. An archive is a sequence of bytes that represent serialized C++ objects.
- The class `boost::archive::text_oarchive` **serializes** data as a **text stream**, and the class `boost::archive::text_iarchive` **restores** data from such a **text stream**.
- Constructors of archives expect an **input or output stream** as a parameter. The stream is used to serialize or restore data.

<sup>source: https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.serialization-archive</sup>

I understand that I must pass a stream as a parameter to the archive. However, there are a few different types of streams which are suitable candidates. See the following digram:

[image: stream types]

<sup>source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8116698/3599179</sup>

I have seen online serialization examples that used `ostream` and `istream`, other examples used `ostringstream` and `istringstream` and some others used `streambuf`, which acts as both an input and output buffer if I am not mistaken.

(File streams are out of the equation because I need to write/read from a socket not from a file.)

- What advantages/disadvantages offer each of the aforementioned streams?
- Considering that I must send the serialized objects over UDP, which
  stream is the best candidate?

Comment: @user463035818 I have added the image source.

Comment: Considering that you want a stream, and probably reliable delivery, UDP is perhaps not the ideal choice.

Comment: @molbdnilo UDP is a formal requirement, so I *must* use it with all its consequences. Streams are required by the Boost.Serialization archive, not because I want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take time to read descriptions of the streams you mentioned on [cppreference.com Input/output library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io), it is quite instructive.

If you want to serialize into memory only one stream works for you: `ostringstream`. Then you extract the string from it and send it however you please. For deserialization use `istringstream`. Alternatively, `stringstream` for both cases.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Maxim's answer, if you really want to use UDP, you need to take care of splitting your stream into datagrams and ensure consistency of the data stream yourself. UDP is datagram-oriented and comes with no guarantees of data consistency.

What needs to be taken into account when using UDP:

- Datagrams may get lost in transit.
- Datagrams may arrive more than once.
- Datagrams may become corrupted in transit (there is a checksum but it's optional and weak).
- Datagrams may arrive out-of-order.
- The bandwidth of the network or the recipient may be insufficient for the rate at which the sender is sending.

If any of these are an issue, you need to implement appropriate countermeasures as part of your protocol, e.g. a packet sequence number and a way to request packet retransmission.

Large datagrams may get fragmented and severely reduce performance. Some people recommend a max datagram size of 512 bytes.

So, given these restrictions, I would suggest to use a ***compact***, binary serialization format. For example, protobuf or msgpack. Boost isn't very compact, though can be good enough (source: [cpp-serializers](https://github.com/thekvs/cpp-serializers)).

Comment: The benchmark of the serializers was really helpful. Thank you.