# C++; mirror and pass through from std::basic_istream<>?

Tags: c++, istream

**GIVEN**:

A class `MyStream` derived of `std::basic_istream<>` contains a pointer `subject` to a `std::basic_istream<>` object. It shall respond to `tellg()` and `read()` with modified content from the corresponding responses of `subject`.

```
template <class T> MyStream :
   public std::basic_istream<typename T::char_type, typename T::traits_type> {

   std::basic::istream<...>*   subject;

   ...
};
```

**PROBLEM**: The functions `tellg()`, `seekg()` and `read()` as well as the status-flag functions are not virtual.

**QUESTION**: How can a `MyStream` object pass tell, seek, and read to subject, forward the response to the caller and modifiy the status flags so that they correspond to the flags of `subject`?

Comment: The trick is to use a different / derived [`streambuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) in your derived stream class. [SO: What exactly is streambuf? How do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8117182/7478597)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
template <typename T> struct MyStream : public std::basic_istream<typename T::char_type, typename T::traits_type> {
   struct rdbuf_impl : public std::basic_streambuf<typename T::char_type, typename T::traits_type> {
       // overwrite what you need
       std::basic::istream<...>* subject;

       // for tellg passthru (an example)
       pos_type seekoff( off_type off, std::ios_base::seekdir dir,
                      std::ios_base::openmode which = ios_base::in | ios_base::out ) overwrite {
           return subject->pubseekoff(off, dir, which);
       }
   };
   MyStream(std::basic::istream<...>* subject) {
       auto v = new rdbuf_impl(subject);
       rdbuf(v); // set associated stream buffer 'v' in 'this'.
   }
};
```

EDIT:
Let's consider `tellg` method. Looking at definition of class `basic_istream::tellg` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg) - it is written, that `tellg` will call `rdbuf()->pubseekoff(0, std::ios_base::cur, std::ios_base::in)`. Documentation for `basic_streambuf::pubseekof` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/pubseekoff) mentions, that it will call `seekoff(off, dir, which)`. `seekoff` is virtual in `basic_streambuf` class and you can overwrite it.

Comment: Would you, please, elaborate on your solution? How can I forward calls to `tellg()` etc to `subject`? How is the state of `subject` reflected in the status bits of a `MyStream`?

Comment: Sorry, I undid the checkmark, because, I can still not see how the flags and `read()` function could be handled. It currently seems to be insanely complicated. Why would I need a buffer and cannot pass the data through without intermediate storage?

Comment: You stated problem, that `tellg` and friends are not virtual and how to pass information around. I gave you a solution in form of an example solving `tellg` issue. Others are solved similarly. It is complicated due to a design of C++ library, which is like 20 years old, if not older.

Comment: It's a bitter pill, but I guess I have to swallow it--you're right. (There were marvelous library designs made 40 years ago, so no excuse to the I/O-library developers ... or maybe, I am missing the point of brilliance).